# I want to shutdown and no shutdown the ports of the Switch

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi3, cisco, pysnmp

My switch is a Catalyst 2960-x series, I already configured with SNMP, Im using now PySNMP, but Im new at this, I already know that the command that I have to use is this "sudo snmpset -v 2c -c   SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.105.1.1.1.3.1.13 i 2". But im not getting it done, can someone help please.

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import*
setcommunity = 'EuricoFerreira'
host = '192.168.150.231'
port = 13

snmp_engine = SnmpEngine()

set_gen = setCmd(snmp_engine,
                 CommunityData(setcommunity),
                 UdpTransportTarget((host, 161)),
                 ContextData(),
                 ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-SMI', 'mib-2', '105.1.1.1.3.1.%d' % port), Integer(2)))

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(set_gen)
if errorIndication or errorStatus:
    print('SNMP error: %s' % errorIndication or errorStatus)
else:
    print('SNMP succeeded')
```

This code is giving me this errors:

```
" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 878, in writeTest
  File "<string>", line 570, in writeTest
  File "<string>", line 469, in writeTest
  File "<string>", line 766, in getBranch
pysnmp.smi.error.NoSuchInstanceError: NoSuchInstanceError({'idx': 0, 'name': (1, 3, 6, 1, 6, 3, 18, 1, 1, 1, 8, 115, 45, 55, 50, 50, 51, 54, 51, 55, 52, 52)})

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/pysnmp-4.3.2/snmpTest.py", line 17, in <module>
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(set_gen)
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/pysnmp-4.3.2/pysnmp/hlapi/asyncore/sync/cmdgen.py", line 210, in setCmd
    lookupMib=options.get('lookupMib', True)))
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/pysnmp-4.3.2/pysnmp/hlapi/asyncore/cmdgen.py", line 231, in setCmd
    addrName, paramsName = lcd.configure(snmpEngine, authData, transportTarget)
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/pysnmp-4.3.2/pysnmp/hlapi/lcd.py", line 44, in configure
    authData.securityName
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/pysnmp-4.3.2/pysnmp/entity/config.py", line 71, in addV1System
    ((snmpCommunityEntry.name + (8,) + tblIdx, 'destroy'),)
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/pysnmp-4.3.2/pysnmp/smi/instrum.py", line 250, in writeVars
    return self.flipFlopFsm(self.fsmWriteVar, vars, acInfo)
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/pysnmp-4.3.2/pysnmp/smi/instrum.py", line 218, in flipFlopFsm
    rval = f(tuple(name), val, idx, acInfo)
  File "<string>", line 470, in writeTest
  File "<string>", line 1117, in writeTest
  File "<string>", line 1088, in __delegate
  File "<string>", line 886, in writeTest
  File "<string>", line 793, in createTest
  File "<string>", line 699, in createTest
  File "<string>", line 591, in setValue
  File "<string>", line 289, in setValue
AttributeError: 'RowStatus' object has no attribute 'hasValue'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest pyasn1/pysnmp. From the traceback it looks like you are running some old pyasn1.

Comment: Thanks man I made it i was not with the version of the pyasn1 and also i was with the version of pysnm 4.3.2, it had to be with the version 4.3.5.

Comment: Now I have another question, how can I know the state of my switch port ? 
So i can turn ON or OFF the port ?

Comment: You should use SNMP GET command instead for SNMP SET one. In pysnmp terms you should change `setCmd` for `getCmd` and drop the value part in `ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-SMI', 'mib-2', '105.1.1.1.3.1.%d' % port))`. That way you will read current port state instead of setting it to certain state.